# will go support mips in the future

Tags: go

go 1.0 does not support mips.

Will go support it in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC 4.7 has a *Go* front-end (with the *gccgo* command) and can be built, as a cross compiler, for MIPS target.